# How do you sort an array of words with Ramda?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Sorting numbers is easy with Ramda.

```
const sizes = ["18", "20", "16", "14"]
console.log("Sorted sizes", R.sort((a, b) => a - b, sizes))
//=> [ '14', '16', '18', '20' ]
```

Sorting an array of words with vanilla javascript is too.

```
const trees = ["cedar", "elm", "willow", "beech"]
console.log("Sorted trees", trees.sort())
```

**How would you sort an array of words with Ramda.

If you had to.**

```
const trees = ["cedar", "elm", "willow", "beech"]
console.log("Sorted trees", R.sort((a, b) => a - b, trees))
//=> ["cedar", "elm", "willow", "beech"]
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use native method?

Comment: @charlietfl Might be because the native method requires mutation of an existing object, unlike `R.sort`

Comment: I guess the native sort mutates the current list whereas ramda sort returns a copy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
import R from 'ramda'

const names = ['Khan', 'Thanos', 'Hulk']

const sortNamesAsc = R.sortBy(R.identity) // alphabetically
const sortNamesDesc = R.pipe(sortNamesAsc, R.reverse)

sortNamesAsc(names) // ['Hulk', 'Khan', 'Thanos']
sortNamesDesc(names) // ['Thanos', 'Khan', 'Hulk']
```

[Ramda Repl example](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20names%20%3D%20%5B%27Khan%27%2C%20%27Thanos%27%2C%20%27Hulk%27%5D%0A%0Aconst%20sortNamesAsc%20%3D%20sortBy%28identity%29%20%2F%2F%20alphabetically%0Aconst%20sortNamesDesc%20%3D%20pipe%28sortNamesAsc%2C%20reverse%29%0A%0A%2F%2FsortNamesAsc%28names%29%20%2F%2F%20%5B%27Hulk%27%2C%20%27Khan%27%2C%20%27Thanos%27%5D%0AsortNamesDesc%28names%29%20%2F%2F%20%5B%27Thanos%27%2C%20%27Khan%27%2C%20%27Hulk%27%5D)

Comment: Wonderfully complete answer!

Answer (score 15):

Don't try to *subtract* strings - instead, use `localeCompare` to check whether one string comes before another alphabetically:

```js
const trees = ["cedar", "elm", "willow", "beech"]
console.log("Sorted trees", R.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b), trees))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can create a comparator with [`R.comparator`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#comparator) and [`R.lt`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lt):

```js
const trees = ["cedar", "elm", "willow", "beech"]
const result = R.sort(R.comparator(R.lt), trees)
console.log("Sorted trees", result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean by sort an array of words with Ramda?

```
import R from 'ramda'
var objs = [ 
    { first_name: 'x', last_name: 'a'     },
    { first_name: 'y',    last_name: 'b'   },
    { first_name: 'z', last_name: 'c' }
];
var ascendingSortedObjs = R.sortBy(R.prop('last_nom'), objs)
var descendingSortedObjs = R.reverse(ascendingSortedObjs)
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is sorting an array of objects by a key but thanks you for answer.